# time between saving a file in S3 and invalidating it on Cloudfront. How much time should I wait?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, boto3

I am uploading a file to S3.
The file already exist on S3, so I am overwriting it.

Immediately after that I invalidate the cloudfront distribution.

However,  the file in cloudfront is not refreshed.

If I do the same process again,  then the previous version shows in cloudfront.
That means that it takes a little bit of time to S3 to get the file ready and I am invalidating too fast the cloudfront so it doesnt take the change.

How much time should I wait in between?

BTW, I am using Python Boto3
s3.put_object and cloudfront.create_invalidation

Comment: You are waiting for the invalidation request to actually complete, before testing... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found out that there was a bug in a different part of the code that was writing old data.

**So to be clear:  if you upload a file to S3 and immediately invalidate it,  it will be invalidated.**